# unknown attribute: uploaded_file - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4
Ruby 2.0
Windows 8.1

In my view, I have the following:

```
<%= f.file_field :uploaded_file, label: "Image" %>
```

And in my controller, I have the following:

```
  def create
    @agent = Agent.new(agent_params)
    ........
  end

    def agent_params
      params.require(:agent).permit(:uploaded_file, :first, :last, :email)
    end
```

When I try to create an agent, I get the following error message:

```
    unknown attribute: uploaded_file
```

and it points to this line of code:

```
@agent = Agent.new(agent_params)
```

uploaded_file is in the list of permitted params and I can see it in params (looking through the log file). Any ideas?

Comment: I assume it's added to your model too?

Comment: My model? as it's in the agent table in the DB? no, it's not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get `unknown attribute error` when the specified field does not exist in the given Model.

In your case, `uploaded_file` is neither a field in `agents` table nor a virtual attribute(defined by `attr_accessor :uploaded_file`) in `Agent` model which is causing the error.

To resolve this you would either have to add a field named `uploaded_file` to `agents` table or add a virtual attribute in `Agent` model as `attr_accessor :uploaded_file`.

**NOTE:** 
Just for your reference, check out [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) and [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gems which provide easy file attachment management for ActiveRecord.

Comment: Yes, except that this is NOT an activerecord related file upload. Both carrierwave and paperclip rely use activerecord. I misunderstood how this works now with Rails 4 as I was under the impression that if I have it in the permit list in my controller, I no longer need to use attr_accessor in my model even if the attribute is not part of the table

Comment: Adding attr_accessor to the model did solve the problem